# How can I make my character look like it is made out of spaghetti noodles?

Tags: mesh, node-editor, geometry-nodes

i have been thing  about making a character which is litterally made of spagetti or wires, something lik that
its a little similar to these two images i want the human character but for now to show i have a silloette of a person[image]

and i also have this character i found with the kind of wires or curves [image]

as you can see i have a character model in the shape of a person, but i want to use nodes to change the mesh into multiple messy wires that clump and look like they where all tangled together, i have seen a post like this before however i have lost it so this is my i am asking this question

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3CwKkiJZN0&ab_channel=WiresoulStudio

Comment: thanks this is my answer!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, I've made a setup which uses the setup from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3CwKkiJZN0&ab_channel=WiresoulStudio, but in Geometry nodes.

It looks very close, but has a lot of noodles going out from shape:

[image]

I believe it might help future googlers.

Comment: when you finish with it, does it convert to mesh?

Comment: curve to mesh in the end as you see

Answer (score 8):

If you enable the shipped add-on 'Add Curve: Extra Objects', then 'Knots > Bounce Spline' becomes available.

It will generate a spline which fills the object which is active at the point of creation:

[image]