# Volume colonization by capillaries/roots

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, mesh, add-on, obj

I'm trying to render a 3D space (defined by an object) occupied by randomly generated capillaries or roots. Imagine a gel with blood capillaries developed inside it.
The result would be something similar to what can be obtained with Ivy Generator add-on, but with a tridimentional distribution of the capillaries inside the selected object instead of placing them just on surface of the object.

Does anybody have any idea about how to do it?

Thank you

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261818/how-can-i-make-my-character-look-like-it-is-made-out-of-spaghetti-noodles

Answer (score 1):

The new (version 3.4) **shortest edge paths** nodes takes a start vertex on your geometry and finds the shortest path along the edges.  By adding noise and resampling the curve, you get interesting branching structures.  Of course it only generates these lines on the surface of the object, but you can scale it down.   For example, Suzanne here:[image]

The node tree looks a little like this.  It uses a null object to select which side of the object the shortest edge paths will start from.:

[image]

In order to get mesh, you have to convert the curves.
[image]

Another interesting effect also generated with geometry nodes is called the **plexus effect**. It basically throws some random points in your volume and connects the dots, but it takes a lot of math to figure out how to that. There are some great youtube tutorials demonstrating how to put together the node trees.   like this, which is also Suzanne:

[image]

While I don't understand all the math required to create the plexus effect, (I referenced Entagma on Youtube) basically it involves faking a loop in geometry nodes by copying the positions of all the end points, and connecting them based on distance.

[image]

I thought it would be interesting to combine what I had learned about the shortest edge paths and the plexus effect together and see what would happen. It turns out it takes a lot of nodes to do what I had in mind, but it does work.  I think by creatively setting the materials of the skin and capillaries, you can get something very organic.  Combining it with the ivy generator will certainly yield some interesting results.

[image]

[image]

I am trying to send my blend file, maybe you can experiment with it.